# Simple resizable array

Tags: c++, array, memory-management, c++14

In some (lower-level) parts of my codebase I often have the need to allocate **resizable array storage** for certain objects, that usually are not *default-constructible*.

I created a simple class using `std::aligned_storage` and I was wondering if it's **safe** and if it can be **improved**.

The user of the class has to keep track of the current capacity.

```
template<typename T> class ResizableArray
{
    private:
        using TStorage = std::aligned_storage_t<sizeof(T), alignof(T)>;
        TStorage* data{nullptr};

    public:
        ~ResizableArray() { delete[] data; }

        void resize(std::size_t mSizeOld, std::size_t mSizeNew)
        {
            auto newData(new TStorage[mSizeNew]);
            for(auto i(0u); i < mSizeOld; ++i) newData[i] = std::move(data[i]);

            delete[] data;
            data = newData;
        }

    auto& operator[](std::size_t mIdx) noexcept 
    { return reinterpret_cast<T&>(data[mIdx]); }

    const auto& operator[](std::size_t mIdx) const noexcept 
    { return reinterpret_cast<const T&>(data[mIdx]); }
};
```

Example usage:

```
int main()
{
    ResizableArray<Thing> a;

    // Resize array capacity from 0 to 10
    a.resize(0, 10);

    for(auto i(0u); i < 10; ++i)
        new (&a[i]) Thing{/* something */};

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why not using [std::vector::`reserve()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) and [std::vector::`emplace_back()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back)? [`vector<T>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) does require `T` to be default-constructible.

Comment: `std::vector<T>` only requires T to be default constructable if you features of vector that use the default constructor. If you don't use those features then this requirement is not required because of SFINAE. So the only thing stopping you using a vector is re-size. Rather than use re-size just reserve and emplace back your elements that you want.

Comment: Forgot the rule of three. Forgot to make resize provide the strong exception guarantee.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see a couple of problems:

- If you ever shrink the array, the loop for copying the elements will overrun the bounds of `newdata` because the index runs from 0 to `mSizeOld`.
- You don't store the size of the array in the class, so code like this will lose data:

  ```
  ResizeableArray<Thing> a;
  a.resize(0, 10);
  // Populate the array
  a.resize(0, 11);
  // Now a is empty again because resize() uses the first argument.
  ```

  This might be intentional — to allow you to start over with a fresh set of data &mdash but if so, `resize()` should be commented to say that.

Comment: Thanks for the review. The array is meant to never be shrunk - I will probably rename it to `GrowableArray` or something similar. I added an assertion to make sure `mSizeOld <= mSizeNew`. Not storing the size of the array is intentional (as not calling the items' destructors is) - I will make sure to document that properly.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo If you are renaming it to `GrowableArray`, rename the method from `resize` to `add`. Instead of 2 parameters, you accept the number of items to add. And prepare a method to get the length of your 'array'.

Answer (score 5):

Ciao Vittorio,

You're looking for safety and improvements, thus I'll give a brief overview of the code and then focus on them.

### Overview

1. You're abusing `auto`: in a lot of places, you don't really need it such as in `for` loops.
2. I can't see any library `#include` but you'll need at least `<memory>` and `<cstdint>`.
3. Your code will not compile for non `DefaultConstructible` classes.
4. There is no way to get the number of elements.
5. Following #4, it's hard to extract a range from it and/or iterate over it.

### Safety

The `resize` function has some faults:

1. There is no check against `mSizeOld` and `mSizeNew`, therefore `mSizeOld` can easily be `> mSizeNew`. `mSizeOld` should be a member of the class.
2. If `mSizeNew == mSizeOld`, elements will be however copied/moved.

### Improvement

1. You could make `resize` a variadic template in order to create elements with such arguments.
2. Check for `mSizeOld` and `mSizeNew` and `throw out_of_range/` if you find something wrong.

Answer (score 4):

It seems to me that it would be beneficial to store the length of the array as well. It is such a tiny increase in the size of the structure that I really don't see why wouldn't you do it.

If you do keep track of the size, then you could do debug bounds checking inside `operator []`, which I consider very important.

As it was mentioned, there is a bug in the `for` loop of `resize()`, as the new array is allocated with `mSizeNew` entries and the loop will visit `0` to `mSizeOld-1` entries. There is nothing preventing `mSizeOld` from being greater than `mSizeNew`.

You could also use a `unique_ptr` to manage the memory so that you don't have to bother writing an explicit destructor.

Apart from that, good code.

Comment: (Copy-paste from the above answer) Thanks for the review. The array is meant to never be shrunk - I will probably rename it to `GrowableArray` or something similar. I added an assertion to make sure `mSizeOld <= mSizeNew`. Not storing the size of the array is intentional (as not calling the items' destructors is) - I will make sure to document that properly.

Answer (score 3):

#### Summary:

1. rule of three                                   Potentially broken if misused.
2. Strong Exception Guarantee:        Potentially broken depend on T.
3. Naming convention:                      Maintenance
4. Excessive auto keyword:              Maintenance.

### Did not implement the rule of three (five)

```
int func()
{
    ResizableArray<int>   a;
    ResizableArray<int>   b;

    a = b;   // leak `a` original content.
}  // Double delete on pointer.
```

### Did not provide *Strong Exception Guarantee*

```
// in resize

        delete[] data;    // If any element throws.
                          // You have lost all your data
                          // and this element is not in a consistent state.

        data = newData;   // and this assignment will never happen.

// Always do it like this:

        swap(data, newData);  // New data is now in the object.
                              // the old data is in `newData`
                              // We have finished updating the state of `this`
                              // So we can now do dangerious things and not
                              // worry too much.

        delete [] newData;    // Even if there is an exception
                              // This object is in a consistent state.
```

### Naming convention.

Personally I am not into abstract naming conventions (as it usually means you have failed in giving your variables (including members) names that make the code obvious to read). But when I do use them I try to use accepted standards:

```
void resize(std::size_t mSizeOld, std::size_t mSizeNew)
```

Usually a prefix `m` or `m_` means member variable. These are obviously not members.

### Excessive use of the auto keyword

Auto is very useful of makeing the compiler do work. And I agree that there are a lot of cases where it should be used.

**BUT** I also believe that excessive use can make the code confusing and when it removes information from the person reading the code that is not good. In this case:

```
auto& operator[](std::size_t mIdx) noexcept 
{ return reinterpret_cast<T&>(data[mIdx]); }

const auto& operator[](std::size_t mIdx) const noexcept 
{ return reinterpret_cast<const T&>(data[mIdx]); }
```

I think that auto hurts the reader of the code. This is an external interface. If I am going to use your class I don't really want to know the internals I want to know how to use it which means I need to know whats coming out of these functions. To actually I work this out I need to generate some compiler errors or look into your code when I just want to read the interface.

In this case I would expect:

```
T& operator[](std::size_t mIdx) noexcept 
{ return reinterpret_cast<T&>(data[mIdx]); }

T const& operator[](std::size_t mIdx) const noexcept 
{ return reinterpret_cast<const T&>(data[mIdx]); }
```